# How To Show A Div Using ng-show by value from return

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to show/hide a div according to a value returned in a config setting return{}. If the UserProfileLinkData is set to 1, I want to show them the bottom , if it is set to 0, I want to show them the top .

The return is in a configurationService which is called as dependency in the controller for this view. I know this is working because I can call LinkToken from configurationService.

```
return {
  UserProfileLinkData: 1,
  LinkToken: userLinkToken
}
```

The below is the view and the 's that I'd like to hide/show according to this value.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" ng-show="UserProfileLinkData === 0">
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-if="!user.IsLinked" ng-click="openFindPrescriptionModal()">Find My Profile</a></li>
    <li ng-show="false"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Add my Dependents</a></li>
</ul>



<ul class="list-unstyled" ng-show="UserProfileLinkData === 1">
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-if="!user.IsLinked" ng-click="openFindPrescriptionModal()">Link My User Profile</a></li>
    <li ng-show="false"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Add my Dependents</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is code from the controller

```
angular.module('User.Controllers').controller('homeController', function    ($scope, $rootScope, $modal, userService, configurationService, accountService,$location) {

$rootScope.showNavbar = true;
$scope.user = userService.GetUserInformation();
$scope.updatingAcct = true;
$scope.loading = false;
$scope.UserProfileLinkData = configurationService.UserProfileLinkData;
...
```

Comment: Check out this Plunkr based on your question: http://embed.plnkr.co/hqhfM7JIvabou2RW4Sos/preview . Is there something I'm missing because it looks like it's working fine?

Comment: use "==" instead of  "===" in your view ;)

Comment: @austinthedeveloper Thanks for the plunk. I had syntax error in my controller. Works perfect. Boom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this :

```
ng-show="UserProfileLinkData === 0" 
ng-show="UserProfileLinkData === 1"
```

for this :

```
ng-show="UserProfileLinkData == 0"
ng-show="UserProfileLinkData == 1"
```

It work for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are assigning the UserProfileLinkData Service variable to a variable inside the controller for this view with the same name. Are you doing this? Can you show the code for your controller and the state service that is injected?

Comment: I have updated my question with relevant controller code. Thansk

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the "$scope" attribute for the variable you want to access in ng-show. Try using -

```
return {
    $scope.UserProfileLinkData: 1,
    LinkToken: userLinkToken
}
```

After that, you can use the same HTML code without any changes. Try and let me see if this works.